# Interpolating species data from sample points in a small area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, kriging, density, inverse-distance-weighted

I have sample data from a small site (10 acres) which shows the number of occurrences of a particular species of snail over two sampling periods (fall and spring sampling). I want to try and interpolate the potential concentration across the entire site based on the sample data.

Any suggestions on how to best do this?

IDW?

Kriging?

Density?

Comment: This sounds like a regression problem.  Do you use R?  What is your desired output?

Comment: Was hoping to creating a surface model representation of the data. So raster output.

Comment: You will need to incorporate multispectral data like Landsat into your analysis and predict the results based on a model (e.g. glm, RF, SVM, etc).

Comment: Actually the sample size is way to small to model anything so never mind. Thanks for the advice thought.

Comment: Is there any extra information about this area and about the place where the observations were done? If not, I would go with IDW. It is simple and you don't have any information about biological/environmental process.

Comment: To compare IDW and Krigging,I think for snail movement there would be a directional bias/correlated distance effect so go for Kriging not IDW.

Comment: this link would be helpful you can understand interpolation methods and logical behind them http://webapps.fundp.ac.be/geotp/SIG/interpolating.pdf